# Evaluate the following limit: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n}{\frac{r}{n^{2}+n+r}}\right)$

Tags: limits, summation

> Evaluate the following limit:
>
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n}{\frac{r}{n^{2}+n+r}}\right)$$

The answer given is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Squeeze it:
$$
\frac{r}{n^2+n+n}\leq\frac{r}{n^2+n+r}\leq\frac{r}{n^2+n}
$$

Comment: OP wants the sum of the series, not the limit of the sequence.

Comment: @alex.jordan: The hint is excellent, it leaves the OP something to do.

Comment: Ah, my comment stemmed from not seeing how the hint could help :) +1

Comment: @alex.jordan The hints says, for all $n$, that $$ \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{r}{n^2+n+n} <leq \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{r}{n^2+n+r} <leq \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{r}{n^2+n}$$ Now consider what happens when $n$ grows large. What happens to the difference between the upper limit and lower limit?

Comment: Best method i think +1

Comment: @Sasha Yes, My reply to Andre was meant to convey that I now understood clark's hint.

Answer (score 2):

Yes I have got it thank you. First put the expression as $\frac{r}{n^2+n+n}$ and then evaluate the limit. It will become $\frac{1}{2}$. Now put the given expression as $\frac{r}{n^2+n}$. Again the value will come out to be $\frac{1}{2}$. So from Sandwich Theorem we will have the limit as $\frac{1}{2}$. Thanks again

Comment: In a course, **much** more detail would need to be supplied, like an explicit summation.